# Vue computed property not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue component with a computed property i use to produce a list, it works on an array grouped by first letter..
see

https://jsfiddle.net/c6gtj1hw/

```
if (details.length > 0) {
   accum.push[curr];
}
```

the push to accumulator isnt working as i would have expected. Is there something obvious im missing?

Comment: you should do `accum.push(curr)` with `()` not with `[]`

Comment: d'oh... silly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accum.push[curr];` is trying to access the property `curr` on the `push` method. You need to pass `curr` in as an argument:

`accum.push(curr)`